# Exposing a function from Java to Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

It's easy to make objects available to Rhino from Java using `ScriptableObject.putProperty`, but is there a way to expose a top-level function? That is, can I make it so scripts in Rhino can call `foo()` and have that call out to Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Umm... [yes, you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Scripting_Java). Perhaps I'm not understanding your question correctly (what do you mean by "top-level function"?) but if you've exposed java object to Rhino, you can call its methods.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. While I can expose an object, which allows me to call foo.bar(), I'd ideally like to just call bar(). So, by 'top-level function' I mean a function that's a property of the Rhino Scope that's currently executing, if that makes more sense.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can define a FunctionObject: https://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/FunctionObject.html and associate it with global (or your current) scope via putProperty()